# How can this commit vanish from git history?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am unable to understand why a particular commit seems to have just vanished from my git history even though I can see it from a previous commit in my branch.

You can see that `master` contains the tag `v2.1.1.332`:

```
$ git branch --contains v2.1.1.332
* master
```

Here's the commit log for `lib/facebook-ios-sdk` from `master`:

```
$ git log --format=%h master -- lib/facebook-ios-sdk
4b23dc7
3cc007d
b14fbda
3e5c85d
ab962d1
d3da048
d765573
```

Note that `lib/facebook-ios-sdk` is a git submodule, not a regular path in my git repo.

And commit log for the same path from `v2.1.1.332`:

```
$ git log --format=%h v2.1.1.332 -- lib/facebook-ios-sdk
e5ed45f
4b23dc7
3cc007d
b14fbda
3e5c85d
ab962d1
d3da048
d765573
```

Notice the commit `e5ed45f`; its apparently present in `v2.1.1.332` but not in `master`! How is this possible?

Even more interesting, `git-branch` indicates that `master` *does* contain `e5ed45f`:

```
$ git branch --contains e5ed45f
* master
```

Also, when I run `git log master`, I do get `e5ed45f` in the list. Its just that I don't see this commit when I specify the path with `git log`.

Why am I asking all this? While this in itself is a curios state of things, we noticed that the submodule `lib/facebook-ios-sdk` had erroneously been set to a previous commit (the one in `4b23dc7`'s tree). We started looking for the bad commit using `git log master -- lib/facebook-ios-sdk` and that's when we encountered this. Right now we have no idea how this submodule's commit was changed to a previous value.

**EDIT** wereHamster on #git pointed me to `git log --full-history`. Using this option does show the missing commit:

```
$ git log --format=%h --full-history master -- lib/facebook-ios-sdk
e5ed45f
4b23dc7
3cc007d
b14fbda
3e5c85d
ab962d1
aa43dc3
d3da048
d765573
```

However it still doesn't explain why the wrong commit is checked out for the submodule:

```
$ git show --format=%b e5ed45f -- lib/facebook-ios-sdk


diff --git a/lib/facebook-ios-sdk b/lib/facebook-ios-sdk
index cb42580..de7509b 160000
--- a/lib/facebook-ios-sdk
+++ b/lib/facebook-ios-sdk
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit cb425807b1f25f916e48b35e06197bccc8b881be
+Subproject commit de7509b8bff6df7163738a979567a72fd4a13ff8

# This command was run on master
$ git submodule lib/facebook-ios-sdk
 cb425807b1f25f916e48b35e06197bccc8b881be lib/facebook-ios-sdk (v1.1-20-gcb42580)
```

Comment: If the commit is pruned when you don't use `--full-history` then it must be on a branch that had no effect on your selected path when merged. Can you re-run the `--full-history` with `--graph`?

Comment: Thanks -- `git log --full-history --graph -- lib/facebook-ios-sdk` gave a bunch of merge commits alongwith the previous output. We had previously identified the culprit -- it was a merge commit on a topic branch which should have included the change but didn't. However the output of the `--full-history --graph` included too many merges for it to be meaningful. We got to the culprit by manually diffing all the merges between the two heads.

Comment: What do you mean by "culprit"? Isn't your question about why a particular commit is pruned from a given log output?

Comment: Yup the question is specifically about why the commit is pruned from the git log output. However I also explained the real reason why I asked this question (just before the edit) i.e. why should the submodule be set to an older commit when the most recent commit related to this submodule apparently was `e5ed45f`.  The "culprit" in this case was a merge commit on a topic branch which ostensibly included the submodule's commit when master was merged into it but actually did not i.e. we (inadvertently) reverted the submodule's value before committing the merge.